# FileProvider: content downloaded from FTP server not showing up inside directory

Tags: ios, swift, ftp

I'm trying to download a file (namely 'xp-en.zip') from a certain server. I've already checked that this file exists using contentsOfDirectory(::), but for some reason, after the download is completed the file doesn't show up in the directory it was supposed to have been copied to. I'm using XCode and I thought it could have something to do with the app's permissions (since the destination directory is .documentDirectory), but I tried changing it to the main bundle to no avail.

I also tried downloading from another server ('speedtest.tele2.net') but it didn't work either.

```
let credential = URLCredential(user: "anonymous", password: "123456", persistence: .permanent)
let fileManager = FileManager.default

func FTPDownloadUpload(download: Bool = true, server: String, path: String){
    let localFilePath = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    guard let url = URL(string: server) else{
        print("Invalid URL")
        return
    }
    let FTPProvider = FTPFileProvider(baseURL: URL(string: "ftp://" + server)!, mode: .passive, credential: credential, cache: URLCache())
    if download{
        FTPProvider?.copyItem(path: "/" + path, toLocalURL: localFilePath, completionHandler: {x in print("Download completed")})
        //I know this completionHandler closure kinda sucks but I don't know what else to put inside it. Keep in mind my program doesn't have anything to do after calling this function

    }else{
        //This is the upload section. Didn't include it to keep the code shorter
    }
}
```

My function call is:

`FTPDownloadUpload(server: "176.74.128.88", path: "xp-en.zip")`